# '[<UIProxyObject> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key containerView

Tags: swift, interface-builder

when i try to init my controller from storyboard in code I have an error : "

```
Missing proxy for identifier UpstreamPlaceholder-Kat-VH-9Yv.
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIProxyObject 0x7fad23db07f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key containerView".
```

I already deleted in storyboard file and re-create my `containerView` with all connections & referents but its didn't help. Also I try to delete APP from simulator, change simulator, clean project and restart Xcode(8.0).

Comment: Search with ⇧⌘F for `containerView`. There is probably a dead connection in Interface Builder.

Comment: already do it when delete  `containerView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check if you using Storyboard references**

If **YES** - **remove them** and use push/present from code.

I already had similar situation and references was a reason of crashes. I don't know why, but sometimes adding them in one place can lead to crash in absolutely another without any connection. Only using step-by-step restore I found a reason